# jquery scroll through all division

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
      scrollTo : function(speed, easing) {
        return this.each(function() {
          var targetOffset = $(this).offset().top;
           $.fx.off = true;
          $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, speed, easing);

        });
      }
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) 
    {

    if(e.keyCode == 78) { 
        navigation_x();
    }

    function navigation_x(){
    $('div#images-interface-controller').scrollTo(1000);

}
```

So i have this keyup function that everytime i press letter "n" it will scrollto to the div#images-interface-controller, yes it was scrolling but till' to the last element of the the div#images-interface-controller. How can i stop it, i mean i want it to scroll just 1 at a time everytime i press "n". I guess the .each above the jquery code has something to do with my problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Anyways, i am using this plugin:
http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: Just have an array of IDs to scroll to, then when "n" is pressed cycle through them...

Answer (score 0):

I've used this plugin before, but it's been a while. I think you want this.

```
$(window).scrollTo('#images-interface-controller', 1000);
```

The selector that `scrollTo()` is called on is the item that is doing the scrolling, whereas the selector that is passed as the first parameter is the object you want the first item to scroll to.

This is telling the `window` to scroll to a certain item, specifically the div with the `id` of `images-interface-controller`.

Comment: Your sample scroll to the first id of the div but not on every div when i press "n".


I was trying to stop it from looping at the very end of the division i want it to stop and then loop at the next id of the division when i press "n".